# import user session data to other django app

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms, django-views

I have a django project with two apps, the first is called 'main', where the user can login and register and all the authentication stuff is made and the other is 'app' where only authenticated users can access.

Main.views:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, f"New account created: {username}")
        login(request, user)
        return redirect("app:app_index")

    else:
        for msg in form.error_messages:
            messages.error(request, f"{msg}: {form.error_messages[msg]}")

        return render(request = request,
                    template_name = "main/register.html",
                    context={"form":form})
        
form = UserCreationForm
return render(request = request,
              template_name = "main/register.html",
              context={"form":form})
```

All the code works fine and allows me to login, register, logout... but now I need to export that user to the 'app' app in order to use the user data on the app template, how can I migrate the user and all its data?

I wonder I would be able to just do

app.views:

```
from main.views import user
```

but definitely this does not work, any suggestion will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can simply access use information an all your apps with object notation.

In my case, the user object has `username` attribute, so when I want to use the users' username I can simply type

```
user.username
```

And it will return the username saved on the database for the specific user that's loged in